# Will the Core i3 stock cooler fit in a 2U case?

Tags: dimensions, cpu-cooler

I can not find the dimensions of the Core i3 stock cooler anywhere.

Will a Core i3 stock cooler fit in a 2U rackmount case?

Comment: Even if it did, you wouldn't want to use it. Rackmount gear is designed to intake from the front and blow out the back, stock Intel coolers blow top-down. This isn't a big deal in desktops, because of the extra space, but it makes a big difference in a rackmount setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it fits. The core i3 stock cooler is about 6-7cm tall and [you have 88.1mm in a 2U case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack). Considering the motherboard is raised a little bit, the fan should fit marginally. But as mentioned by MarkM, you won't want to do that.